# A question on vector space over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{F}_{2^\sigma}$ be a finite field of $\sigma$-bit elements, and use $\mathbb{F}_{2^\sigma}^{\ell}$ to denote an $\ell$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{2^\sigma}$. Let $V$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_{2^\sigma}^\ell$ such that any $\ell$ vectors in $V$ are linearly independent. The question are:

1. Is it possible that $|V|>\ell$?
2. How to find such $V$ of maximum size?

$\big($The questions are not very hard to answer for vectors over real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. In that case, "yes" to the first question, and $V=\{e_1,\dots,e_{\ell}\}\cup\{[1, x,\dots,x^{2^\sigma-1}]| x\in\mathbb{F}_{2^\sigma}\}$. So $|V|=2^\sigma+(\ell-1)$.$\big)$

Comment: I don't understand your example of a set $V$. Doesn't your notation imply that $2^\sigma$ equals $l$ in this case? Also why do you write 'In that case' if the example is clearly not over the reals?

Comment: You are looking for the main conjecture for MDS codes. It is possible that $|V| > \ell$.